# How is 깨끗하다 pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-korean

I can pronounce it both ways below:

1. 깨끋타다
2. 깨끄타다

I think #2 is the correct way but when I listen to this word's pronunciation on Google Translate, which you can slow down, it sounds like #1.

Comment: 깨끄타다 is the only correct pronunciation for 깨끗하다. Do not trust Google Translate; it can give you wrong pronunciations (and also mistranslations).

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think the Korean sound system has a meaningful distinction between "깨끋타다" and "깨끄타다".  In other words, there is not a meaningful difference between /V1 ㅌ V2/ vs. /V1 ㄷ ㅌ V2/, where V1 and V2 are some vowels.

So it's a bit like asking whether English "taillight" is pronounced with one l or two l's: the point is moot, because English does not have the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

깨끄타다 is correct way because ㄷ and ㅎ conjunctures.

1st step. 깨끗하다->깨끋하다 (음절의 끝소리 규칙)

2nd step. 깨끋하다->깨끄타다 (음운 축약)

The first step happens when the last phonology is not ㄱ,ㄴ,ㄷ,ㄹ,ㅁ,ㅂ,ㅇ and the latter word has a meaning. When the first step happens, the last phonology becomes one of the letters I mentioned above.
As 깨끗하다= (깨끗+하)+다, and 깨끗 and 하 have meanings, 깨끗 becomes 깨끋.

The second step occurs when ㄷ, ㄱ, ㅂ meets ㅎ when pronounced sequently.

- ㄷ+ㅎ->ㅌ,
- ㄱ+ㅎ->ㅋ,
- ㅂ+ㅎ->ㅍ.

깨끋타다 will emphasize your opinion.

Also ㄴ,ㄹ,ㅇ,ㅁ have some difference with other consonants, as we wrinkle when we pronounce these consonants. So 충분하다 doesn't conjugate to 충부나다.

Comment: On Naver and Google translate,  충분하다 is pronounced like it's written, i.e. "충분하다". They definately do not say "충부나다".

Comment: @James it's possible for ㄴ+ㅎ pronunciation to be different from ㄷ+ㅎpronunciation

Answer (score 0):

Middle sound of G and K is required when you speak ㄲ

[G'K] ae [G'K] eut Ha Da

in korean [깨끄타다] is right way to pronounce.